# how can extract one row having not null values from a few of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

for example

tableA has

| id | condition_A | condition_B | condition_C | condition_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | NULL | NULL | 10 | NULL |
| AA | 15 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| AA | NULL | NULL | 10 | 5 |
| AA | NULL | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| AA | NULL | 20 | NULL | 5 |

every condition has same value with same id

then i want to extract result like

| id | condition_A | condition_B | condition_C | condition_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 15 | 20 | 10 | 5 |

how can extract without null and only one rows?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(condition_A), max(condition_B), max(Condition_C), max(Condition_D)
from tableA where id = 'AA'
```